# How do I fix "Failed to execute C/C++ compiler" error when building helix grammer?

Tags: treesitter, helix-editor

## Problem:

When I run the `hx -g build` command to build the tree-sitter grammars Helix throws the following error:

```
Building 123 grammars
123 grammars failed to build

    Failure 0/123: Failed to execute C/C++ compiler
    Failure 1/123: Failed to execute C/C++ compiler
    Failure 2/123: Failed to execute C/C++ compiler
    ...
    ...
    Failure 122/123: Failed to execute C/C++ compiler
    Failure 123/123: Failed to execute C/C++ compiler
```

Running `hx -g fetch` succeeds with this message:

```
Fetching 123 grammars
123 up to date git grammars
```

### System specification:

- **Helix**: 22.12 (96ff64a8)
- **Clang**: 16.0.0
- **Clang++**: 16.0.0
- **PowerShell**: 7.3.3
- **Windows**: 22H2

### Expected result:

Tree-sitter grammars build successfully.

### What I tried:

1. Found this [wiki](https://github.com/helix-editor/helix/wiki/Troubleshooting#failed-to-execute-c-compiler-building-from-source) on troubleshooting this specific issue, but there is not enough information provided on which C/C++ compiler I need to install.
2. Tried using different compiler (gcc 11.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you already resolved this or not.

I got the same issue, and had to install both `gcc` and `g++` on Debian Bookworm:

`sudo apt install gcc g++`

Comment: Not sure about that because I'm on Windows 10 machine. However, I fixed it by installing Visual Studio build tools for C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [Visual Studio build tools for C/C++](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build%20tools) fixed it for me.